# Oracle formatting csv address with optional fields and duplicate values

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an Oracle PLSQL function that returns an address (called from sql) in a comma separated format, for example:

```
, 7 Hawaii Street, Windhoek, Windhoek, 9000, , , , ,
```

The addresses are stored in many different styles and therefore a field could be blank (even address line 1 if for example the person is not living in a flat).

There is also an optional leading space before each field.

I would like to print the output in the following format without blank lines in between

```
7 Hawaii Street,Windhoek,Windhoek,9000
```

or even

```
7 Hawaii Street,Windhoek,9000
```

My attempt was the following (which removes the spaces before each field and removes double commas; but completely loses the Windhoek):

```
select ltrim
         (
            replace
            (
               replace
               (
                  regexp_replace
                  (
                     xxpay_bi_util.get_address   -- varchar2
                     (
                         p_person_id       => papf2.person_id,   -- in number
                         p_effective_date  => trunc(nvl(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:EFFECTIVE_DATE), sysdate)),   -- in date
                         p_type            => 'full',            -- in varchar2
                         p_include_null    => 'Y',
                         p_include_country => 'N'
                     ),
                     '([^,]+)(,[ ]*\1)+'
                  ),
                  ',,', ','
               ),
               ', ', ','
            ),
            ','
         )  csv
```

Can anyone help me fix this so that it does not loose the Windhoek?

Comment: How is the data stored in the DB in the first place? If it is stored in separate columns and the string is built before it is passed to your PL/SQL function, change the code that builds the comma-separated string in the first place. It looks like your DB uses a single space as placeholder (replacement) for NULL, and then you use LISTAGG or similar... that can be fixed at the source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
trim( ',' from regexp_replace(str, '(,\s*)+', ','))
```

It replaces every occurrence of (one or more commas, each followed by zero or more spaces) by exactly one comma. Then it trims leading and trailing commas, if any.

With that said, as I mentioned in a Comment, it is likely that the string is built from base data to begin with. **THAT** building of the string in the first place is what should be fixed, then you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WITH t AS 
    (SELECT LEVEL AS Item_no, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(', 7 Hawaii Street, Windhoek, Windhoek, 9000, , , , , ', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS item 
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(', 7 Hawaii Street, Windhoek, Windhoek, 9000, , , , , ', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT listagg(item, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Item_no)
FROM t
WHERE item IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: `where item is not null` is not needed, since `listagg()` ignores nulls.

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    ', 7 Hawaii Street, Windhoek, Windhoek, 9000, , , , , ',
    '\s*,\s*',
    ','
  ),
  '^,+|,+$|(,),+',
  '\1'
)
```

**Output**:

```
7 Hawaii Street,Windhoek,Windhoek,9000
```

**Getting rid of duplicates**:

```
WITH addresses ( address ) AS (
  SELECT ', 7 Hawaii Street, Windhoek, Windhoek, Windhoek County, Windhoek County, 9000, , , , , ' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT LISTAGG( address_part, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY lvl ) AS address
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS lvl,
         t.column_value AS address_part,
         CASE WHEN LAG( t.column_value ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM )
                   = t.column_value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_duplicate
  FROM   ( SELECT ROWID AS id,
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(
                    REGEXP_REPLACE( address, '\s*,\s*', ',' ),
                    '^,+|,+$|(,),+',
                    '\1'
                  ) AS address
           FROM   addresses
         ) a
         CROSS JOIN
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( a.address, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( a.address, '[^,]+' )
             ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
           )
         ) t
)
WHERE  is_duplicate = 0
GROUP BY id;
```

**Output**:

```
ADDRESS
---------------------------------------------
7 Hawaii Street,Windhoek,Windhoek County,9000
```